# How do I prevent nil value from causing an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a method that is called on a button to update to different counts under my herd model. UI count and NUI count. See method below

```
def refresh_ui_and_nui_count
  if params[:herd_id].presence
    herd = Herd.find_by_id(params[:herd_id])
    if herd.nil?
      flash[:error] = t('Unable to find herd')
    else
      herd.set_ui_count
      herd.set_nui_count
    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
   format.json {render json: {ui_count: herd.ui_count, nui_count: herd.nui_count}, status: :ok}
  end
end
```

I added a check to see if herd is nil (Line 4) however, theoretically the format.json line could also fail. What could I use to prevent  this from failing in the event that there is no herd_id?

Comment: try this: `format.json { render json: { ui_count: herd&.ui_count.to_i, nui_count: herd&.nui_count.to_i }, status: :ok}`. this will return `ui_count` and `nui_count` as `0` if `herd` is blank if that's ok for your case, else you can remove `.to_i`.

Comment: Ah yes, a simple rescue. I was overcomplicating it. Since the ui and nui count are integers the '&' rescue should to the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably if there is no such entity, you need to response with 404 error

```rb
def refresh_ui_and_nui_count
  herd = Herd.find(params[:herd_id])

  herd.set_ui_count
  herd.set_nui_count

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { ui_count: herd.ui_count, nui_count: herd.nui_count }, status: :ok }
  end
end
```

And somewhere in parent controller

```rb
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_not_found_response

def render_not_found_response(exception)
  render json: { error: exception.message }, status: :not_found
end
```